# How can one change the battery saver to dark mode in Android 9 (Samsung Galaxy S9)?

Tags: applications, dark-mode, battery-saver

I use Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9.

Screenshot from the Google Drive Android application, which seems to indicate that it is possible to change the theme in the battery saver:

[image: Google Drive providing 'Set by Battery Saver' for theme]

How can one change the battery saver to dark mode in Android 9 (Samsung Galaxy S9)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The "Set by Battery Saver" option only means that the app's theme is determined *if Battery Saver is enabled or not.***

The Battery Saver itself does not have its own theme, but apps can query if the setting is enabled or not for customizing its behavior, including the theme.

On Google Drive (and some other Google apps, and possibly 3rd-party apps), this setting means that *if Battery Saver is enabled, then use the theme that saves battery (e.g. dark theme)*.

To summarize:

- Dark: always use the dark theme
- Light: always use the light theme
- Set by Battery Saver:

  - If Battery Saver is **off**: use the light theme
  - If Battery Saver is **on**: use the dark theme